# Build variable resistor controlled by Arduino

Tags: arduino, pwm

I would like to build a variable resistor that can be controlled by Arduino. My plan is to vary resistance between the two values, i.e., 1 ohm to 10ohm, to continuously change the load for a small wind turbine. The resistances are for dissipating the power from the wind turbine, and the performance of the wind turbine is determined by the magnitude of the resistance. Would you please let me know how to build such system? Especially, I would like to know how to interface between the two power resistors and the Arduino control board.

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2013/10/28/building-a-dc-constant-currentpower-electric-load/

Comment: What sort of power dissipation are you talking about?

Comment: If you have two resistors of 1 ohm and 10 ohm that's all you have unless you have a plan to be able to alter one of these "fixed" values.

Comment: Thanks your comments. I would like to have any intermediate value between them. The two values are lower and upper bounds.

Comment: Can you use a 1 Ohm load and switch it on and off at some duty cycle?

Comment: The purpose of power dissipation is just to dump out the produced power by the wind turbine. The only thing I would like to is to measure the amount of power depending on the magnitude of the load (that I like to control).

Comment: Yes, I think it would be good to put a switch one of two resistor. Do you have good idea what type of switch would be good? and how to adjust duty cycle on that?

Comment: Well, I was just throwing out an idea, but I imagine it might wreak havoc on your turbine. What sort of power does the turbine generate?

Comment: 12V~24V and 20~30W, this is very small research wind turbine.

Comment: Is the wind turbine's output AC or DC?

Comment: The output is DC

Comment: You could always go for a truly gross solution and use an ordinary linear pot. with a linear actuator :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like shown below, where Vin is the input from the turbine, Vr is the voltage used to change the channel resistance of the MOSFET, I is the turbine current, and V across the 10 ohm resistor is the turbine output voltage.

By changing the MOSFET's gate voltage, its channel resistance can be varied from essentially an open to a short circuit, which will cause the parallel resistance of the circuit to vary from 10 ohms to about an ohm if Rds can be driven low enough.

Of course, knowing Rds(sat), the value of the 1.11 ohm resistor could be adjusted to yield precisely one ohm from the circuit, giving you precisely the one to ten ohm range you want.

[image]

Comment: It looks very good. Then, what is difference with connecting two resistance in serial instead of parallel as above? This question is purely for satisfying my curiosity as a student. For controlling MOSFET, is PWM signal usually used?

Comment: 'what is difference with connecting two resistance in serial instead of parallel as above?'Basically, the values of the resistors, the location of the MOSFET and the shape of the transfer function.'For controlling MOSFET, is PWM signal usually used?' It depends on the application; for yours, I don't think so and,BTW, your curiosity as a student can easily search out and find answers by downloading and learning to use a **FREE** copy of LTspice from http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXufnb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you use relays shorting a series string of resistors with values such as 5\$\Omega\$/2.5\$\Omega\$/1.25\$\Omega\$/0.625\$\Omega\$/0.3125\$\Omega\$ (with an unswitched  1.0\$\Omega\$ in series), you can program values from 1.0 ohm to 10.6875 ohms in steps of 0.3125 ohms, using only a few (5 in the above example) SPST relays.

A single ULN2003A will drive up to 7 relays (eg. 10A) with no additional components.

You can think of this as a resistance output DAC with high power capability.

Comment: It looks good, I would rather have a continuous control for that. Since the goal is to test an algorithm finding the optimum load resistance. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have control over your load resistance?